# Pyspark: Dynamically update columns position of a dataframe according to other dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement to change column positions frequently. instead of changing the code i created a temporary dataframe `Index_df`. here i will update the column positions and it should reflect on actual dataframe on which the changes should perform.

sample_df

```
F_cDc,F_NHY,F_XUI,F_NMY,P_cDc,P_NHY,P_XUI,P_NMY
415    258   854   245   478   278   874   235
405    197   234   456   567   188   108   267
315    458   054   375   898   978   677   134
```

Index_df

```
   col   position
    F_cDc,1 
    F_NHY,3
    F_XUI,5
    F_NMY,7
    P_cDc,2 
    P_NHY,4
    P_XUI,6
    P_NMY,8
```

here according to the `index_df`,`sample_df` should change.

Expected output:

```
F_cDc,P_cDc,F_NHY,P_NHY,F_XUI,P_XUI,F_NMY,P_NMY
415    478   258   278   854   874   245   235
405    567   197   188   234   108   456   267
315    898   458   978   054   677   375   134
```

here column positions are changed according to the positions i have updated in `Index_df`

I could do `sample_df.select("<column order>")` but i have more than 70 columns. Technically which is not a best way to deal.

Comment: Why is it a problem for you to perform a select on 70 columns ? i dont see any limitations.

Comment: Cant you do that in the next steps ? Where do you display the information ? probably, you should do the "cosmetic" part after the pyspark step, where you use or display your data

Comment: @ Steven BENET: currently i have the above requirement for 70 column table, after i need to perform the same on tables having more columns. please suggest solution for above post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with `select`.

First, you retrieve your columns in the right order :

```
NewColList = Index_df.orderBy("position").select("col").collect()
```

Then you apply your new order to your df

```
sample_df = sample_df.select(*[i[0] for i in NewColList])
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `collect` will give you `Row` objects? You can either use `select("col").as(String)` or `collect.map(_.getAs[String]("col") )` whichever works best is pyspark.